# Detect Windows Mobile vs. "plain" Windows CE

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-ce

How can my Compact Framework application detect whether it is running under **Windows Mobile** (Start Menu at top, Menu bar at bottom) as opposed to **"plain" Windows CE** (Start Menu at bottom, Menu bar inside the application)?

Since Windows Mobile runs on top of the Windows CE kernel, `Environment.OSVersion.Version` does not really help here (it just returns the CE kernel version number).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would kindly refer to Microsoft's MSDN FAQ posting under [>> VSD FAQ <<](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/9a532e5f-cafe-44d7-84d1-ca42606c96f3), this is Item #10: [How do I detect the platform and Windows Mobile version?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/9a532e5f-cafe-44d7-84d1-ca42606c96f3#x_FAQAnswer10)

I would repost, but there is a small code sample and several links in the post that would be time consuming to duplicate here.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Framework 3.5, there's a property [`SystemSettings.Platform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsce.forms.systemsettings.platform%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in the `Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms` namespace which provides this information (returning `WinCEGeneric`, `PocketPC` or `Smartphone`).

Answer (score 2):

You can also check for the existence of the Microsoft.WindowsMobile and Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status assemblies ... CE doesn't contain these additional add-ons that WM layered on top of the CE code-base.

Answer (score 1):

We use something like this.  But each CE device will probably return a different string.

```
        [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool SystemParametersInfoGetString(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, System.Text.StringBuilder pvParam, uint fWinIni);

                System.Text.StringBuilder platformBuff = new System.Text.StringBuilder(100);
                if (SystemParametersInfoGetString(SPI_GETPLATFORMTYPE, (uint)platformBuff.Capacity, platformBuff, 0))
                    return platformBuff.ToString();
```